# how to put an input value 1 in an input 2 use jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have 2 input, i want when i click on button validate the value of input 1 puts in the input 2 and also it's input 1 empty give a message fill input 1.
help plz.
knowing that the button validate hide the form 1 and display the form 2:

```
    <div id='form1'>
     <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <label>number day 1</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="nombre de jour 1">
     </div> 
           <table class="table table-bordered">
   <tr>
      <td>aa</td>
      <td>bb</td>
      <td>cc</td>
      <td>dd</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="hit">click</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>ee</td>
      <td>ff</td>
      <td>gg</td>
      <td>hh</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="hit">click</a></td>
   </tr>

</table>

 <div class="form-group col-md-offset-5 ">
    <button id="hide" class="btn btn-success " type="submit">valider</button>
  </div>

</div>
<!------table2 ------>
<div id='form2'>
   <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <label>Number day 2</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="nombre de jour 2">
    </div>  

   <table class="table table-bordered">
   <tr>
      <td>rr</td>
      <td>rr</td>
      <td>rr</td>
      <td>rr</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="hit">click</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>rr</td>
      <td>rr</td>
      <td>rr</td>
      <td>rr</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="hit">click</a></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

jquery code to hide form1 and display form2:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){

    $("#form1").hide();
  });
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $("#form2").show();
  });
});

</script>
```

the CSS code to hide the form 2 at the start:

```
        <style>
    #form2{
display:none;
}         
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set id for input and use

```
let value = $('#input1').val();
$('#input2').val(value);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
let value = $('#input1').val();

if (value == ""){
   $('#error').show();
}else{
    $("#form1").hide();
     $("#form2").show();
     
     $('#input2').val(value);
 }
  });
  
});
```

```css
#form2{
display:none;
}

#error{
color:red;
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='form1'>
     <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <label>number day 1</label>
       <input type="text" id='input1' class="form-control" placeholder="nombre de jour 1">
       <span id='error'>Input can not blank</span>
     </div> 
           <table class="table table-bordered">
   <tr>
      <td>aa</td>
      <td>bb</td>
      <td>cc</td>
      <td>dd</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="hit">click</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>ee</td>
      <td>ff</td>
      <td>gg</td>
      <td>hh</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="hit">click</a></td>
   </tr>

</table>

 <div class="form-group col-md-offset-5 ">
    <button id="hide" class="btn btn-success " type="submit">valider</button>
  </div>

</div>
<!------table2 ------>
<div id='form2'>
   <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <label>Number day 2</label>
       <input type="text" id='input2' class="form-control" placeholder="nombre de jour 2">
    </div>  

   <table class="table table-bordered">
   <tr>
      <td>rr</td>
      <td>rr</td>
      <td>rr</td>
      <td>rr</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="hit">click</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>rr</td>
      <td>rr</td>
      <td>rr</td>
      <td>rr</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="hit">click</a></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much, the code is it works, but it remains just a small problem is that when input 1 empty it must give me a message "must fill input 1", how to do that ??

Comment: I update answer for showing message if input 1 empty